# strpos с отрицательным смещением

Tags: php

согласно документации код верный, почему не находит позицию?

```
var_dump(strpos('hello word!', 'o', -2));//false
```

проверил на php 7.1, 7.3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**-2** в вашем примере это сдвиг с конца строки на то место, от куда начнётся поиск. Вы сдвинули указатель на **d**. Надо учитывать тот момент, что сдвиг с конца строки происходит от индекса **1** а не **0**, как это происходит при поиске от начала строки. И  вернёт, в случае нахождения, позицию искомого, начиная с начала строки и с индекса **0**.

```
strpos('hello word!', 'o', -2); // указатель стал на d и пошёл слева направо
```

Comment: да, спасибо, теперь понятно, я думал, что это зеркально, т.е. с права на лево пойдёт

Answer (score 4):

Потому что ни 'd', ни '!' не являются 'o'.

Comment: "Если задано отрицательное значение, отсчет позиции начала поиска будет произведен с конца строки."  https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.strpos.php

Comment: Ну и вторая позиция с конца это d. И как уже написано вы ищете __о__ в __d!__.